# Rate limit policy per user with Microsoft.AspNetCore.RateLimiting middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to implement a rate limiting behavior with Microsoft.AspNetCore.RateLimiting middleware into a asp.net 7 application.
I need to partition by currently authenticated user based on custom auth approach.

Q: I'm looking for an advice what is the proper way to do it.

Currently I'm trying the approach of dynamically define a policy per authenticated user and apply the policy dynamically as well. But i'm not really sure is this going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to partition with the following simplified code:

```
services.AddRateLimiter(limiterOptions =>
{
    limiterOptions.AddPolicy(CustomerEmailsRateLimitPolicyName, context =>
    {
        var userId = GetUserId();

        return RateLimitPartition.GetSlidingWindowLimiter(
            userId,
            _ => new SlidingWindowRateLimiterOptions
            {
                PermitLimit = xxx,
                Window = xxx,
                SegmentsPerWindow = xxx,
                QueueProcessingOrder = xxx,
                QueueLimit = xxx
            });
    });
});
```

Where it can be placed in the Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can partition by custom key which can be simply some unique UserId or a combination of UserId + some other identifier.

You can define PartitionedRateLimiter. Following example has separate limits for userId and specific url or endpoint, and it uses sliding window of 1 minute, and some constant PERMIT_LIMIT that defines number of allowed requests per minute:

```
public static PartitionedRateLimiter<HttpRequestMessage> CreatePartitionedRateLimiter(Guid userId, string url)
        {
            var key = $"{userId}/{url}";

            return PartitionedRateLimiter.Create<HttpRequestMessage, string>(resource =>
            {
                return RateLimitPartition.GetSlidingWindowLimiter(
                    key,
                    key => new SlidingWindowRateLimiterOptions 
                    {
                        AutoReplenishment = true,
                        PermitLimit = PERMIT_LIMIT,
                        QueueLimit = int.MaxValue,
                        QueueProcessingOrder = QueueProcessingOrder.OldestFirst,
                        SegmentsPerWindow = 1,
                        Window = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
                    });
            });
        }
```

After that, you define a handler:

```
internal class RateLimitedHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly PartitionedRateLimiter<HttpRequestMessage> _rateLimiter;

        public RateLimitedHandler(PartitionedRateLimiter<HttpRequestMessage> limiter) : base(new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            _rateLimiter = limiter;
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using RateLimitLease lease = await _rateLimiter.AcquireAsync(resource: request, permitCount:  1, cancellationToken);
            if (lease.IsAcquired)
            {
                return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests);
            if (lease.TryGetMetadata(MetadataName.RetryAfter, out var retryAfter))
            {
                response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.RetryAfter, ((int)retryAfter.TotalSeconds).ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
```

and at the end HttpClientFactory that uses this partitioned rate limiting:

```
internal class MyHttpClientFactory
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, HttpClient> httpClients = new();

        public static HttpClient GetRateLimitedHttpClient(Guid userId, string url) 
        {
            var key = $"{userId}/{url}";
            if (!httpClients.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                var rateLimiter = PartitionedRateLimiterFactory.CreatePartitionedRateLimiter(userId, url);

                var client = new HttpClient(new RateLimitedHandler(rateLimiter))
                {
                    BaseAddress = new Uri(...),
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
                };

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-api-key", channexSettings.ApiKey);

                httpClients.TryAdd(key, client);
            }

            return httpClients[key];
        }
    }
```

In order to get the Client and call some endpoint you just use factory:

```
var client = MyHttpClientFactory.GetRateLimitedHttpClient(userId, url);
var res = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```